# Not able to overriding css class !important with inline style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using bootstrap-select for custom combo box, in their external css the have give class

```
.hide{ display: none !important; }.
```

Im also using same class .hide{display:none}. But without !important. In all the area I just remove it if I want to show the element. In some area I have used jQuery slide down instead of removing ".hide" class. Bootstrap-Select affectes where I have used jQuery slide down.

Kindly assist me.

Comment: is using script OK? if it is you should add tag `javascript` to your question.

Comment: You can resolved this issue either using JS/Jquery or CSS.
Temporary please create one more css file and add ".hide{ display: block !important; }".
Now Please add new CSS file reference in your page either in above/below "bootstrap" css. You will get idea.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display an element that was hidden using the class name `.hide`, you should remove that class instead of setting inline styles.

```
document.querySelector( '.myComboBox' ).classList.remove( 'hide' );
```

Comment: Thanks for  immediate reply. Im not setting inline style, while giving jQuery slide down property jQuery applies inline style display:block. !important property affects this in many area.

Comment: @prakashstar42 There are two bad things going on here: using `!important` and using inline styles. The Bootstrap JS plugins also use jQuery and do remove and set the appropriate class names.

Comment: Sorry I forget to say, Im also using same class .hide{display:none}. But without !important. In all the area I just remove it if I want to show the element. In some area I have used jQuery slide down instead of removing ".hide" class. Bootstrap-Select affectes where I have used jQuery slide down. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your own class to hide elements such as .invisi { display:none; }
this will then work when using JQuery functions such as .show() and .fadeIn()